# Use cell text to define vlookup datatable range

Tags: datatable, vlookup

[image: vlookup example]

In the image above, how do I replace the portion "Tom.A:C" in the vlookup function with the text in cell B2 + .A:C ?

Where "Tom" is the name of a sheet in my workbook and I want to lookup a value in the second column of that sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup,sheet!range,column,match)
```

Then, in your example, you must write it like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, TOM ! [Range of the sheet], 2, FALSE)
```

**Edit:**

I did not understand the first time exactly what was the question, so here it is the answer:

The formula

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup,indirect(concat(<cell with sheetname>,<"!"|".">,"<CELL RANGE IN ALL LOOKING SHEETS>")), column, match)
```

Then in your example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, indirect(concat(A2,".","A:C")), 2, 0)
```

First you need to concatenate the value of the sheet and range that you want, then with indirect, you take that string value and use it as a valid reference.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, I'm familiar with how to use vlookup, I'm not sure how to take the text in cell B2 and use it within the vlookup formula to define the datatable range "Tom.A:C", which would be the second argument to the vlookup formula.

Comment: Thanks Rodrirokr, worked perfectly. If I have another question regarding excel formulas/references, am I able to address you directly? Specifically, if the result of the VLOOKUP is a date, and you want to use that date to subtract from another date, how would you reference?

Comment: Of course you can ask me, you can use the `datediff` function (documented in [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38)), so you can take as parameters the result of the VLOOKUP and the date you want to compare to, also, it takes a third parameter that specifies what kind of date unit you want to make the comparison. Hope that is was you need. P.D. if you can upvote my answer that would be great (: